# Multiple Clicks on button leads to calling button.setOnClickListener multiple times in Android

Tags: android

I have a `button.setOnClickListener()` which inserts data into database, but I have to call `button.setOnClickListener()` only once even it was clicked multiple times, I have tried the below code but it didn't work:

```
int flag=1;

@Override
public void onClick(View v) 
{
    if(flag)
    {
        button.setEnabled(false);
        Log.d("ins", "called");
    }

    flag=0;
}
```

Any suggestions for this is mostly accepted.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
@Override 
public void onClick(View v) {
  // do database stuff
  button.setEnabled(false);
  button.setClickable(false);
  Log.d("ins", "called");
}
```

Database stuff will be executed only once, the button will only be clicked once, as per your requirements.

If you want it to be clickable again, just `setEnabled` and `setClickable` to `true` after your database stuff has finished.

Answer (score 0):

This would probably won't work. The ideal way to get around this:

1. button clicked.
2. disable button.
3. Do work.. Insert records into database.
4. enable button again.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do,

```
@Override public void onClick(View v) {
    if(flag) {
        /* Perform button functions */
    }
}
```